# MacBook Air 13" Mid2013 94% battery drain overnight

Tags: catalina, battery

Two days ago I noticed a strange battery drain so I decided to check for some solutions online. I used the `sudo pmset -b tcpkeepalive 0` method and last night I charged my MacBook Air to 100% and then I closed the lid until this morning when I checked it and it showed a 6% battery charge.

This is the log that I get from the `pmset -g log | grep ' Wake '` command:

```
2020-05-06 21:39:51 +0200 Wake Requests         [*process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2020-05-06 23:39:51] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=371893 wakeAt=2020-05-11 04:58:04 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,464"]           
2020-05-06 23:38:50 +0200 Wake                  Wake from Standby [CDNVA] : due to EC.PME/User Using AC (Charge:100%) 41 secs   
Sleep/Wakes since boot:151   Dark Wake Count in this sleep cycle:1
2020-05-06 23:39:34 +0200 Wake Requests         [*process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=364709 wakeAt=2020-05-11 04:58:04 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,464"]           
2020-05-07 10:25:15 +0200 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to EC.LidOpen/Lid Open Using BATT (Charge:6%) 44 secs   
2020-05-07 10:25:15 +0200 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [AppleIntelFramebuffer driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(385 ms)]           
Sleep/Wakes since boot:152   Dark Wake Count in this sleep cycle:1
2020-05-07 10:26:16 +0200 Wake Requests         [*process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=325908 wakeAt=2020-05-11 04:58:04 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,464"]           
2020-05-07 10:26:19 +0200 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderDriverNub driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(447 ms)]           
2020-05-07 10:26:24 +0200 Wake Requests         [*process=bluetoothd request=Maintenance deltaSecs=895 wakeAt=2020-05-07 10:41:19 info="com.apple.bluetoothd-blueavengers"] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=325899 wakeAt=2020-05-11 04:58:04 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,464"]
```

The only thing plugged all night into the MacBook were my headphones: is it possible that they caused this huge battery drain?

Power Nap has always been disabled. The Mac is updated to the latest macOS official release.

From `pmset -g` this is what I get:

```
Currently in use:
 standbydelaylow      10800
 standby              1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 gpuswitch            2
 powernap             0
 disksleep            10
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 sleep                1 (sleep prevented by timed)
 autopoweroffdelay    28800
 hibernatemode        3
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         2
 highstandbythreshold 50
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```